# www.dropbox.com redirects to 127.0.0.1 to piratebay.org and does not load

Tags: networking, dropbox

I recently installed Win10

I normally use PC, install sw, and suddenly when I want to download dropbox, I see ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
so tried to trace route it but it shows this:

Tracing route to [www.dropbox.com](http://www.dropbox.com) [127.0.0.1]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  thepiratebay.org [127.0.0.1]

Trace complete.

Can someone help with advice how this emerged and how to solve it?
Thank you
Petr

Comment: Can you go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and show the contents of the `hosts` file? It sounds like you might have some "protection" program that redirects domains to your localhost `127.0.0.1`. Alternatively you might want to [change your DNS server](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-pcs-dns-settings-windows-10) to one of the public ones such as Google DNS (8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4) or Cloudflare (1.1.1.1 & 1.0.0.1).

Comment: Somebody may have actively configured your computer not to be able to go to piratebay or dropbox.  Is this computer your own?

Answer (score 0):

Check your HOSTS file for any wierd entries.

1. Press Win+R, then enter `notepad %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.
2. Look if there are any suspicious entrys like `127.0.0.1 thepiratebay.org`.
3. Back them up just to be sure.
4. D E L E T E

Comment: thank you all, the hosts file is full of weird addresses that seem to be clones of piratebay and dropbox is among them, I erased them all and it all works fine, maybe I ran some app that did this, should install also an antivirus.

Comment: @Petr call me paranoid but if I were you, I'd immediately turn it off, boot into a live Linux distro to back up any non-backed-up files, and cleanly reinstall the whole OS. It may be the safer option in case there's a rootkit or if the AV doesn't find the underlying virus.